# Should primitives be centered in a 3d engine?

Tags: opengl, center, mesh, primitive, vertices

So, I'm adding physics to my game engine right now and the physics engine expects the vertices of a primitive to be distributed around 0,0,0. Now my primitive cubes vertice positions range from 0 to 1 in every dimension. Should I center the cubes around 0,0,0 or shift the vertices when giving them to the physics engine AND when reading the position of the rigidbody ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the physics engine, but normally it's easiest to work with if the physics system can assume the object's center of mass is at 0,0,0. For your cube primitives, if you think about rotating and scaling them, you should quickly come to the conclusion that a 0,0,0 center is convenient for those operations as well.